# What to use for initial values? Struct, enum or class, #defines c++

Tags: c++, oop, enums

It's kind of a shame to ask this question and probably will fit better in the Code Review site, so sorry in advance.

My question is the following (can be extensible for other languages since is more OOP):

I have a class:

```
class Unit
{
public:
Unit(Type);
Type type;

private:
int weaponry;
int shielding;
int hull;
int rapid_fire;
}
```

with an enum to differenciate between different types of units.

```
enum Type{
    Cruiser,
    Missile
};
```

All the units will be initialize with a default value (plus a factor, depending in external variable).

```
Unit::Unit(Type type)
{
    this->type = type;

    int weaponry, shielding, hull,rapid_fire;
    switch(type){
    case Cruiser:
        weaponry = 2700;
        shielding = 50;
        hull = 400;
        rapid_fire = 5;
        break;
    case Missile:
        weaponry = 200;
        shielding = 20;
        hull = 80;
        rapid_fire = 0;
        break;
    }

    this->weaponry = weaponry ; //+ whatever
    this->shielding = shielding; //+ whatever
    this->hull = hull; //+ whatever
    this->rapid_fire = rapid_fire; 
}
```

I will also have a method that will change the values of the object, such as the typical

```
setHull(int newHull){this->hull = newHull}
```

In one of these methods, i want to revert one of the private variables to its default value, in the example case, if is Cruiser this->shielding = 50, if its a missile = 20.

My questions are the following. 
Am i doing something wrong?

I have several options to keep the defaults values, either with (the one I would "noobly" will choose)

```
#define initial_cruiser_shielding 50
```

either with enum:

```
enum shielding_init{
    cruiser_i = 50,
    missile_i = 20
};
```

to have default instances of the basic objects, and then just copy them and create as many new objects I need.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you already recognize that it belongs on Code Review, why not post it there?

Comment: Did you ever hear about inheritance?

Comment: @Zéychin this question its more about general OOP than just an specific code (thats what I can understand for what is for Code Review, but if you think fits better there, I will move it there :)).

Comment: @Sambuca, i guess you are talking something like: abstract class unit (with all the getters setters) and specific classes for each type of object (ship in this case) such as class Cruiser : public unit, and here have the initialize values?  Thanks guys for your fast response!

Comment: @DavidSánchez Yes... In terms of OOP you should not deduce the type of an object based on a variable. Your objects should be instances of specific types. Consider adding new types with the same fields to your solution, you'll end up adding everything in your Unit class.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation will be to create private static member functions that can return default values.

```
class Unit
{
   public:
      Unit(Type);
      Type type;

      int set_default_weaponry()
      {
         weaponry = get_default_weaponry();
      }

      int set_default_shielding()
      {
         shielding = get_default_shielding();
      }

      int set_default_hull()
      {
         hull = get_default_hull();
      }

      int set_default_rapid_fire()
      {
         rapid_fire = get_default_rapid_fire();
      }

   private:
      int weaponry;
      int shielding;
      int hull;
      int rapid_fire;

      static int get_default_weaponry();
      static int get_default_shielding();
      static int get_default_hull();
      static int get_default_rapid_fire();
}
```